# Can you please explain this recursion, someone? Thanks

Tags: recursion

```
def power(x,y):
    if y==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x*power(x,y-1)

print(power(2,3))
```

The output of the code is 8. Why is it 8, which is 2**3?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Explanation]

Let's say x=2 and y=3

This function will run. And each time it runs it will do x * something_to_get.

Now it tries do find what is that something_to_get.
Well something_to_get = power (x,y-1) (here x=2 and y = 2)
So it do power (x,y-1).
 Also the same thing happen again inside power (x,y-1). It will so x * something_to_get. That something_to_get is power(x,y-1) (here x = 2 and y = 1)

This procedure continue to happen until y = 0. It returns 1.

In the end you will have 
2*2*2*1 = 2**3 = 8

Comment: Thanks EEAH. Are you saying that it is the 2*2 that just keeps recurring and that the only purpose of y in power(x, y-1) is to decrement the number of recursions until y==0?

Comment: @God_is Yes. that is the only purpose of y. Without it the function would continue forever resulting in a endless loop.

Comment: @God_is I updated the answer with an explanation figure. Also used the original input : x=2 and y=3

Comment: I see. Once again, Thanks.